# WindowBuilder doesn't allow all layouts in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, windowbuilder

When I go to Properties of a JPanel, I can't set the Layout to SpringLayout or FormLayout. Is this a limitation of Java Swing or WindowBuilder? If SpringLayout is not available, what would be the best way to have one large panel, and column of smaller components, inside a JPanel?

Answer (score 3):

I've never used WindowBuilder (do you mean the one from [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/)?).

The simplest to me seems to be a `BorderLayout` with your big panel in the `CENTER`. Then an additional `JPanel` in either the `WEST` or `EAST` constraint with maybe a `BoxLayout`.

Comment: plain Swing with default LayoutManagers +1

Comment: I did try BorderLayout, I think I set them to West and East, but I didn't find a way to make one component span most of the space. With MigLayout, I could easily set up the column and row to fill and grow. MigLayout seems to be the best here, though I'm wondering why other layouts were not available for the JPanel.

Comment: The component in the CENTER should fill the entire available space.

Answer (score 0):

Both SpringLayout and (JGoodies) FormLayout are available in WindowBuilder, so this is not a limitation of WindowBuilder. See the docs...

http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/layoutmanagers/swing/springlayout.html

http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/layoutmanagers/swing/jgoodies_formlayout.html

You can see both of them listed right in the Layouts palette...

[image: Layouts Palette]

Comment: I have used SpringLayout for a window, but not inside a JPanel.